# Calculate value from same column but different category within same table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I tried to get `SUM` value by using this query

```
SELECT SUM(nominal) Total_Pemasukan FROM kas WHERE jenis = 'Masuk' AND tanggal = '2019-10-14'

SELECT SUM(nominal) Total_Pengeluaran FROM kas WHERE jenis = 'Keluar' AND tanggal = '2019-10-14'
```

But I don't know how to implement the subtract within the same table based on category I just want to subtract the first and second query.

I'd expect the final result like this

```
500 - 300 = 200
```

here's my table design

```
keterangan |    tanggal     |   jenis | nominal

A,              2019-10-14,     Masuk,  500

B,              2019-10-14,     Keluar, 300
```

Answer (score 1):

A few of ways to do things like this. As subqueries in another SELECT:

```
SELECT 
  (SELECT SUM(nominal) Total_Pemasukan FROM kas WHERE jenis = 'Masuk' AND tanggal = '2019-10-14')
  -
  (SELECT SUM(nominal) Total_Pengeluaran FROM kas WHERE jenis = 'Keluar' AND tanggal = '2019-10-14')
```

Or by subqueries that are cross joined (cross join associates every row from a with every row from b. In this case because a and b have one row each we don't get duplicated data)

```
SELECT 
  m.Total_Pemasukan - k.Total_Pemasukan
FROM
  (SELECT SUM(nominal) Total_Pemasukan FROM kas WHERE jenis = 'Masuk' AND tanggal = '2019-10-14') M
  CROSS JOIN 
  (SELECT SUM(nominal) Total_Pengeluaran FROM kas WHERE jenis = 'Keluar' AND tanggal = '2019-10-14') K
```

Or by conditional agg:

```
SELECT 
  SUM(CASE jenis WHEN 'masuk' THEN nominal END) -
    SUM(CASE jenis WHEN 'keluar' THEN nominal END) Total_Pemasukan 
FROM kas 
WHERE jenis IN ( 'Masuk', 'keluar') AND tanggal = '2019-10-14'
```

I prefer the latter two over putting queries in the select list, but which one will perform better is quite environment/index dependent - Try them!

Answer (score 0):

group these into `subqueries`, then perform `substraction`

```
SELECT 
    (SELECT SUM(nominal) Total_Pemasukan
        FROM kas WHERE jenis = 'Masuk' AND tanggal = '2019-10-14') 
    - 
    (SELECT SUM(nominal) Total_Pengeluaran 
        FROM kas WHERE jenis = 'Keluar' AND tanggal = '2019-10-14')
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
SELECT SUM(nominal) FROM (
    SELECT nominal FROM kas WHERE jenis = 'Masuk' AND tanggal = '2019-10-14'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT -nominal FROM kas WHERE jenis = 'Keluar' AND tanggal = '2019-10-14'
) a
```